# Is the quotient space O(3)/SO(2) a group?

Tags: group-theory, quotient-spaces, quotient-group

I can't figure out how to demonstrate if it is a group or not. I should see if O(3) is a simple group or that SO(2) is a normal subgroup of O(3).

Comment: $O(3)$ is definitely not a simple group, because it has the normal subgroup $SO(3)$. How are you embedding $SO(2)$ into $O(3)$ / which action of $SO(2)$ on $O(3)$ are you considering?

Comment: I don't really know, the course I've taken isn't clear about how a quotient space is made. In fact, the only way I've learned so far is the one I've written in the question: either I demonstrate that the group is simple or I see if the subgroup is normal.

Comment: The question stands regardless.

Comment: I was saying that I don't know how to embed $SO(2)$ into $O(3)$ or what is the action of a group on another group.

Comment: There is no need to be disrespectful. If I am asking it means that I need some help and if you don't want to waste your time then don't answer. I am a physics student and I am trying to learn more than the uncomplete course of Group Theory has offered me.

Comment: You should verify ${\rm SO}(2)$ is not normal in ${\rm O}(3)$. It can be done very quickly: conjugating a rotation by another is the same as applying the second rotation to the first's axis. (And siimlarly for reflections.)

Comment: @Alba A couple of days later, I've come to realize that my previous comment was unnecessarily rude. Sorry, I'll delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't $SO(3)/SO(2)$ as a quotient space just the $2$-sphere $S^2$?
But $S^2$ has no topological group structure
(any orientation-preserving map from $S^2$ to $S^2$ has a fixed point). Then $O(3)/SO(2)$
would be two disjoint $S^2$s and so won't have a topological group structure.

Comment: This is quite a bit more advanced than simply verifying ${\rm SO}(2)$ is not normal in ${\rm O}(3)$.

Comment: $G/H$ makes sense (as a coset space) even when $H$ is not normal in $G$. @anon

Comment: Indeed. Not sure why you're stating that fact.